# UX research for B2B2C

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, user-interviews

I'm a new lone product designer in a tech start-up that's a B2B2C which does not seem to have a process in place to recruit users.

Any advice on how to recruit to end users?

Also, how often should I be researching the business clients and the end users?

Do you keep tapping on the same pool of users?

Comment: There are plenty of services out there that will work with you to set these types of things up. They are your best bet to start, if you don't have something already in place, and you want to get moving.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a growth strategy?  I thin the question needs a bit of expansion before it can stand as a UX question.  Can you give it an edit?

Answer (score 2):

For the business side, assuming that your company has customers, I would look to your customer support team for recommendations of insightful customers. If you don't have a lot of time you probably want to start with articulate, reflective customers who can introspect and tell you about their needs rather than the ones who think they know what they want and yell out feature requests.

For the consumer side, you can do hallway testing, where you just stand next to the coffee machine in your office or building and ask random people for their thoughts, and giving them a gift card for their time.

That's the cheap effective way I'd do research at a small scale, before being able to resource this more properly.

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question to ask and I am placed in a similar role at a B2B2C start-up! I had to find answers quickly to move work along for my team. Here are a few things I researched on and the steps I took towards a solution. They worked pretty well for me.

- These articles were inspiring and helpful in setting the wheels in motion: [5 Tips for Better Design Research Recruiting](https://www.ideo.com/blog/5-tips-for-better-design-research-recruiting?utm_source=The%20Octopus&utm_campaign=400a61f8e9-The_Octopus_Newsletter_5_18_19&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_5a800eadc1-400a61f8e9-181488877), [DIY Recruiting: How to Find Participants for Your Research](https://medium.com/mixed-methods/diy-recruiting-how-to-find-participants-for-your-research-6f9a05dd1a33), [Recruiting user research participants in a scalable way](https://uxdesign.cc/scalable-user-research-recruitment-a3ee4fed3939) and [Finding UX Research Participants](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/04/finding-ux-research-participants/)
- We created a portal and invited customers, friends, and colleagues to sign up for future usability tests. This was our attempt at creating a user research panel to fall back on as and when we need to test.
- I sent an email out to the team members explaining why usability testing is crucial. I included a link for the usability test sign up on the same email and requested them to forward it to eligible friends and family.
- Coffee-shop-guerrilla-usability-tests cannot fail you! [Unboxing: guerrilla usability testing](https://www.boxuk.com/insight/blog-posts/unboxing-guerrilla-usability-testing)
- I agree with qoba's suggestion and talk to people in the organization who aren't directly involved in product development.
- I was suggested to get an ad out on craigslist if all else fails. (I haven't had the need to do that yet and not sure if I recommend it even.)